# Show image in datagridview boolean column instead of the 0/1 value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a `WinForms` desktop app with data grid view.
It loads data from Sql server and I have a bit column `USRstatus` in the table.
The table columns is as follows:

```
USRstatus(bit) , USERNAME, USERTYPE
```

When I load the table in my `DataGridView`, I want to show images instead of 0/1 values.

The images are in the resources:

```
Pharm.propreties.recourses.on
Pharm.propreties.recourses.off
```

EDIT 
At the load of dgv, I created an image Column and inserted it in

```
DataGridViewImageColumn IMG =new 
DataGridViewImageColumn();
IMG.name="status";
DGVUsers.Columns.Insert(1,IMG);
DGVUsers.Columns["USRStatus"]. Visible=false;
```

And then I used for to fill the value of every row depending on the value of the USRstatus value.

```
for (int i=0;i<DGVUsers.RowCount;i++)
{
      If(Convert.ToByte(DGVUsers.Rows[i].Cells["USRStatus"].Value==1)
       DGVUsers.Rows[i].Cells["status "].Value=Pharma.Propreties.Recourcess.on;
      Else
       DGVUsers.Rows[i].Cells["status"].Value=Pharma.Propreties.Recourcess.off;
}
```

It works fine but I want to do it by replacing the whole column, and not creating a new one depending on the other one if that's possible

Comment: In WPF application, we can do this by use Converter. But for WinForms application, please read the below link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/62f5b477-5311-4de5-bc18-fbd29bbfc9e2/setting-an-image-column-in-a-datagrid-view-based-on-a-value-in-the-database-c?forum=winformsdatacontrols

Comment: Do you intend to allow the user to “change” the Boolean value? And it is unclear what you mean by… _”I want to do it by replacing the whole column, and not creating a new one depending on the other one”_ … can you clarify what you mean by “depending on the other one?”

Comment: I don't want to create the column and check the value in the data source and then add it every time I want to refresh the dgv. I want it to be done dynamically. And I will not allow the user to change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the DataGridViewImageColumn in the DataGridView. When you create a new column just choose the type DataGridViewImageColumn. When you want to change the image just set the value.

```
if ()
    DataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = Pharm.Propreties.Recourses.on;
else
    DataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = Pharm.Propreties.Recourses.off;
```

To see if it is on or off you can use the equals method (every type has this):

```
if (DataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value.Equals(Pharm.Properties.Resources.on)
{ }
```

Another way to do this is to use the Tag variable (every winforms control has this - System.Windows.Forms.Control):

```
DataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Tag = true;
```

Then, to get its value:

```
if (DataGridView.Rows[0].Cells.Tag as bool)
{ }
```

or

```
if ((bool)DataGridView.Rows[0].Cells.Tag)
{ }
```

Personally, I like the `as bool` option more, it is more clear and esthetic.

Another way is to create a new control, but it is way more complicated for this purpose.

Good Luck!